# Elasticsearch: Date Range Search based on Oldest Document

Tags: date, elasticsearch, search, range

I am writing to ask: What is the best way to construct a query to satisfy the following requirement: Date range specification in the filter clause of a boolean query so that gte is based on the oldest document in the index.

Consider:

```
...
"filter":
{
  "range":
  {
    "CustomElasticSearchDateTime":
    {
      "gte": "OLDEST DOCUMENT", <-- (How to get the oldest document here based on the index being searched?)
      "lte": "OLDEST DOCUMENT + 6M/M",
      "relation": "WITHIN"
     }
  }
}
...
```

Here is how I am currently get the oldest document from the index:

```
{
    "size": 1,
    "_source": false,
    "sort":
    {
        "CustomElasticSearchDateTime": "asc"
    },
    "query":
    {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

But it does not seem possible to add this query under the gte of the previous query; or, is it possible. Any help here would be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's (currently) not possible to make that kind of query in a single query.

Another way to approach this problem is to leverage the [`date_histogram` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) with a fixed interval of 6 months. The first bucket will necessarily contain all documents from the oldest one to ones created six months after:

```
POST /index/_search?size=0
{
  "aggs": {
    "oldest_docs": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "CustomElasticSearchDateTime",
        "fixed_interval": "6M"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It might not be exactly what you want, but that's the solution that is closest to your need, at least how I've understood it.

Comment: let me know how it works out

Comment: any luck with this?